# How to create a wifi private network

Tags: windows, macbook, network-shares, wireless-networking

Is there a way to create a private wifi network, i.e. for file sharing? Consider there are 2 notebooks (Win-Win or Mac-Win or Mac-Mac) and someone wants to share some content with other. How can I create such kind of network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup an ad-hoc WiFi network.

[Win-Win](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network)
[Mac-Mac](http://www.thinkmac.net/tutorials/2009/7/27/create-wireless-ad-hoc-network-mac-tips-daily-387.html)
Win-Mac - Choose one of the two above options, and connect to the new network as a client on the other PC.

Answer (score 0):

If the Mac-Mac case is Lion-Lion with relatively recent Macs, then just click on the AirDrop icon on the sidebar of any Finder window on each machine. Lion takes care of discovering other recent Lion Macs in wireless range and displaying them in the AirDrop window, and then you just drag files right onto their icons and Lion takes care of encrypted point-to-point high speed wireless transfer of those files.